# jquery trigger - 'change' function

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button set called "pick_up_point" and I have a change handler to detect the radio button that is checked. In the change handler I call a function "clearFields()" which basically clears out the input fields.

```
function clearFields()
{
 $("#Enquiry_start_point").val("");
 $("#Enquiry_start_town").val("");
 $("#Enquiry_start_postcode").val("");
}

$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function()
{
 if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_airport")
 {
  $("#pick_up_airport_div").slideDown();
  $("#start_point_div").hide();
  clearFields();
 }
});
```

I also have a trigger which will retain the view if the form is redisplayed due to a validation error.

```
$('input[name=\'pick_up_point\']').trigger('change');
```

Now when I post the form the trigger is run and it calls the change handler, which of course runs the clearFields() function. So how can I get around this? I don't want the fields being cleared when the form is re-displayed.

Comment: When you post the form, meaning when you submit it?

Comment: Yes that's right, when I submit the form. The page gets redisplayed if there are any validation errors.

Comment: Anyone able to help? Is there any way jQuery can tell whether the form has been submitted or whether it is in its initial state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a custom event handler, like so:

```
$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function()
{
    $(this).trigger("displayForm");
    clearForm();
});

$("input[name='pick_up_point']").bind("displayForm", function() {
 if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_airport")
 {
  $("#pick_up_airport_div").slideDown();
  $("#start_point_div").hide();
 }
});
```

So instead of triggering the change event, trigger the custom `displayForm` handler, like this:

```
$('input[name=\'pick_up_point\']').trigger('displayForm');
```

And now, when `change` is triggered, it works as expected, but for the special case of displaying the form without clearing the input fields, you can simply trigger your new custom event handler.