# jquery trigger - 'change' function

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery trigger - ‘change’ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266774/jquery-trigger-change-function)

I have a radio button set called "pick_up_point" and I have a change handler to detect the radio button that is checked. In the change handler I call a function "clearFields()" which basically clears out the input fields.

```
function clearFields()
{
 $("#Enquiry_start_point").val("");
 $("#Enquiry_start_town").val("");
 $("#Enquiry_start_postcode").val("");
}

$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function()
{
 if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_airport")
 {
  $("#pick_up_airport_div").slideDown();
  $("#start_point_div").hide();
  clearFields();
 }
});
```

I also have a trigger which will retain the view if the form is redisplayed due to a validation error.

```
$('input[name=\'pick_up_point\']').trigger('change');
```

Now when I post the form the trigger is run and it calls the change handler, which of course runs the clearFields() function. So how can I get around this? I don't want the fields being cleared when the form is re-displayed.

Comment: Please don't ask the *exact same* question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266774/jquery-trigger-change-function

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't getting any responses from anyone.

Comment: [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions), [How to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your change function (sorry couldn't resist) to accept a parameter that tells you whether to clear fields or not.

Comment: How? Can I pass the parameter via the trigger at all?

Comment: Yes, the trigger method takes an optional second parameter that is a list of parameters to pass to the trigger method such as .trigger('change', ['arg1', 'arg2']). - "http://api.jquery.com/trigger/"