# How to catch the event change of <select> of multiple when options added dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select, append

i need to catch the change event of a select *after i add an option*.
As i do not want dublicate values to be entered from various controls on the page.
I tried various ways to catch the event after my option is added on to the page.

update : **i want the change event to be fired after i add the option.(Not with the click to the select itself)**

What i tried is below.

```
<script src="/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clickMe").click(function () {
                $('#example').append('<option value="foo">Foo</option>');
            });

            $("#example").find("option").change(function () {
                alert("changed1");
            });

            $("#example").on("change", function () {
                alert('changed2');
            });

            $("#example option").on("change", function () {
                alert('changed3');
            });

            $("#example").change(function () {
                alert('changed4');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="example" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    <button id="clickMe">
        Add an Option
    </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clickMe").click(function () {
                $('#example').append('<option value="foo">Foo</option>');
 $('#example').trigger('change');
            });    

$('#example').on('change', function() {
          //alert
        });
   });
```

Comment: sorry.  i want the change event to be fired after i add the option.(Not with the click to the select itself)

Comment: thank u very much. why did we need a trigger ? why doesn't "on" solve it without a trigger  ?

Comment: Any event handlers attached with .on() are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. As you were adding options and not selecting it,so this needs to be fired manually with the .trigger() method

Answer (score 2):

try using trigger method for the same http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

check this also

[jquery trigger - 'change' function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266774/jquery-trigger-change-function)

@Edit
try this code change

```
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
    $('#example').append('<option value="foo">Foo</option>');
    $('#example').trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: sorry did not get it from the link. could u write the code using the same sample stated above?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Please check now